# EF Core 2.x: cannot apply migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

There are the two projects in my solution: the first (**Web**) has the Startup class and the second (**Db**) has DbContext. I want migrations'd were placed in the Web project.

**Db.ApplicationDbContext**

```
    /* ApplicationUser is derived from IdentityUser */
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

**Web.Program**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

**Web.Startup.ConfigureSevices**

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Web"));
    });
```

The CLI command **Add-Migration First** from the Web project returns

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'Web'. Ensure that you're using the
>   correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic

Target framework is netcoreapp2.0,  EF Core 2.x, AspNetCore.All 2.x (for Web)

How can I resolved it?

Comment: Try adding `-Verbose` to see more about what it's doing.

Comment: Are you still encountering this problem?

Comment: @CalC The issue was resolved just after I run my application (after this migrations were done successfully). Since I'm not sure it's the _actual_ solution I can't answer here

Comment: This solution helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833287/418251