# An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider - ASP.NET CORE Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting below error while run `Add-Migration InitialCreate` migration command. I am using ASP.NET CORE 2.0.

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Table 'Temp.contacts' doesn't exist Unable to create an object of type
>   'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of
>   'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or
>   see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional
>   patterns supported at design time.

To resolved this error, I have tried to add a class that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` but doesn't work it.

Anyone knows why I got this error?

Comment: Could you add your startup.cs + DB context file?

Comment: Yes, I have already added both the files.

Comment: I meant here so we can see if there is something wrong. Because this error basically says that there is a problem with ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: Your Startup project should be the project which is having Startup.cs file. And In package Manager console default project should be the project which is having DBContext file

Comment: Is there any specific setting in startup.cs + DB context file related to migration ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create migrations after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Error with table name "Users".

the reason was that I were using a seeder class and within it I were using this instruction

`if (!context.Users.Any())`

the problem was in it .

I commented it , added migration and then uncommented it.

Answer (score 1):

I had such error after I changed return type of CreateWebHostBuilder in Program.cs from IWebHostBuilder to IWebHost. I suppose that this method is used to add migration, so ensure to check this return type.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSentry();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by following below link.

[Unable to create migrations after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0)

I have created another class that implements IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.

Thanks,