# Unable to use dotnet ef command in cli

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 in  a MVC web applicattion. I **can** use `add-migration` and `update-database` in my PMC and they work fine. **BUT** when I use their CLI commands in Windows Power Shell like `dotnet ef migrations add InitMig` they **don't** work and give this error:

> **The application to execute does not exist**

To make it clear, I adressed the exact project. So  there is no problem about directions. but still `dotnet ef` commands don't work.

I read this Microsoft article and it says I don't need to add any package in my project for NET Core 2.2 apps, to CLI commands work.
[Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

But I added that package to my project to test if `dotnet ef` works, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
         <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

so `dotnet ef` command works and gave its version and the unicorn. Now the problem is I can't use any commands even `dotnet ef migrations list` the error I get in CLI is:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MainDbContext'. For the different
>   patterns supported at design time,

any `dotnet ef` command in CLI reuslts in this error. As I mentioned before these commands work fine in PMC.

**If u need any part of my project just let me know. I'll share it here.**

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet clean` and `dotnet restore` firstly for your project?

Comment: @XingZou yes more than 10 times to make sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are running ef in the correct version of the sdk.

```
dotnet --version
```

You can specify the version by creating a global.json file in the root of your project.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.301"
  }
}
```