# Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>'

Tags: entity-framework-core

I just upgraded from 1.1 to 2.1 and when I run: `dotnet ef migrations add spottedmahn`, I get:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)` or `IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)` in `Program`.

The method **name** matters (I had `CreateWebHost` and it was failing).

For me, "Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project" was a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  It couldn't find my `IWebHostBuilder` so it couldn't use the `ServiceProvider` configured for my `DbContext`.  Using the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833287/185123) might be valid for some people but violates DRY for me.

---

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671330/185123) I ran my migration in verbose mode: `dotnet ef migrations add spottedmahn -v`:

> Finding DbContext classes...
>   Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
>   Finding application service provider...
>   Finding IWebHost accessor...
>   **No CreateWebHostBuilder(string[])** method was found on type 'MyApp.Web.Program'. 
>   No application service provider was found.
>   Finding DbContext classes in the project...
>   Found DbContext 'MyDBContext'.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'MyDBContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time. ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**I then noticed** "No CreateWebHostBuilder found...".  After some experimentation I learned either of these code segments are valid.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

or

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

[The doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#update-main-method-in-programcs) only refers to the `BuildWebHost` method but the verbose log refers it refers to the `CreateWebHostBuilder` method. ‍♂️

Comment: Same thing for Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 - the EF.Tools seem to create their runtime-context using a method named BuildWebHost() in the executing assembly.