# Unable to create an object of type 'Context'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm currently working on a Azure function project In .NET5.

I have the following project structure:

- Function.Application
- Function.Domain
- Function.Infrastructure

When I try to generate a migration, I get the following error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'Context'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here Is some code:

Function.Application.Program.cs:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var localConnectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=information-services-testdb;Integrated Security=True;";
            services.AddDomain(localConnectionString);
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Function.Domain.Injections:

```
public static class Injections
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDomain(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddPersistence(connectionString);

        return services;
    }
}
```

Function.Infrastructure.Injections:

```
public static class Injections
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistence(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<IContext, Context>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient,
            ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        return services;
    }
}
```

This approach works well when I develop regular ASP.NET Core applications. I just choose which project the Context are In, and then just type `Add-migration dbInit`, and It works.

Why does this not work when working with Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to find the real problem.

```
Add-Migration Init -Verbose
```

*There are a lot of ways to help you solve the issues.*

1. [Can add a class that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` inside of your Web project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0/45833287#45833287)
2. [Find real problem and change your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0/52671330#52671330)

**For more details , pls check below post.**

[Unable to create migrations after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0)